# Restrict acces to API Gateway endpoint to VPC in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm trying to limit access to my API Gateway endpoints to requests from my VPC. There are examples of API Gateway Resource Policies, and even a Policy property on the RestApi resource, but I can't figure out how to write a policy that needs the API's ID, when the API hasn't been created yet. 
I have an example of my understanding how a stack should look like, based on the AWS documentation:

```
MyRestApi:
Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
Properties:
  Name: My Great API
  Policy:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal: '*'
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - - ''
              - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
              - Ref: region
              - ':'
              - Ref: accountId
              - ':'
              - Ref: MyRestApi
      - Effect: Deny
        Principal: '*'
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - - ''
              - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
              - Ref: Region
              - ':'
              - Ref: AccountId
              - ':'
              - Ref: MyRestApi
        Condition:
          StringNotEquals:
            "aws:SourceVpc":
              Ref: VpcId
```

The crux is that I can't reference **MyRestApi** in the policy when it's still being created. I'm sure I'm not the only one that wants to do this ... I'd rather think this is a common problem, so there is very likely an answer already I haven't found yet.

Thanks for any help,

Stefan

PS: The documentation I used was https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-policy and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html

Answer (score 3):

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html) the policy supports a special syntax for `Resource` due to this problem.

```
   "Resource": [
     "execute-api:/stage/method/path"
   ]
```

In the comments, they call it:

> // simplified format supported here because apiId is not known yet and partition/region/account can derived at import time

Comment: For me, this resulted in `Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid.`

Comment: Did you try without the comment?

Comment: Actual issue was adding a PolicyDocument object around it, thus the syntax issue. This should be marked as the correct answer. Side note: Yaml is okay with comments using `#`